# How to add a picture as datapoints in a map in R

Tags: r

I am using maps package in R to draw a simple geographic map and then put my data points in it.

My question is that whether there is any way in R to represent data points with a picture of interest, for example, the animal I am working on in my example.

This is just to give a better representation of the distribution of my data points relative to each other for my reader.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use grid package. The `grid.raster` can be used to put some pictures.

Since `maps` is graphic base package , you need to `gridBase` to combine the grid/base graphics.

Here an example:

```
library(maps)
map('usa',boundary=T,fill=T,col='grey')
library(gridBase)
library(grid)
library(png)
vps <- baseViewports()
pushViewport(vps$figure,vps$plot)
camel <- readPNG("camel.png")    ## some animal picture
grid.rect(gp = gpar(fill=NA))

x <- c(-110,-100,-70)
y <- c(30,40,40)

grid.raster(image=camel,x=x,y=y,width=5,   ## it is vectorized
            interpolate=FALSE,default.units = 'native')
upViewport(1)
```

[image]

PS: I am not sure that there are camels in USA...

Comment: There, I knew there was some better way than my answer!  :-)

Comment: @CarlWitthoft it is actually the same idea..but with the grid package.

Answer (score 2):

`rasterImage` is one way, albeit somewhat laborious. Once you've got the images of interest formatted as raster objects, you can then place them at designated locations (and frame sizes) inside your plot region.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the `rasterImage` function mentioned by @CarlWitthoft there is also the combination of `my.symbols` and `ms.image` from the TeachingDemos package for adding images to a plot (base graphics).  The `rasterImage` approach gives the most control, but `my.symbols` is more like the regular plotting functions in that you say plot the images centered at these coordinates (and set other options to specify size etc.)